# C# saving items added to combobox

Tags: c#

I have a combo box that holds employee names that are selected by that employee. When I add a name to the combo box with a button click is there a way to keep the name in the combo box for the next time the program is started? Below is my code to add the employee names that I know need to be in the list and then the code to add a name to the combo box.

```
 private void employeeSelect_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cboEmpName.Items.AddRange(new string[] { "John", "Roger", "Bill", "Jason", "James" });
    }


 private void addTechbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAddTech.Text))
        {
            cboEmpName.Items.Add(txtAddTech.Text);
            txtAddTech.Clear();
            MessageBox.Show("Technician has been added");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter a name to add to the list");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can do this by save employee name in database or some other media (not hard coded in your application).

Comment: You need a storage to load and save data. It can be a database, file, settings, etc.

Comment: If you want to have your data after closing your application, you should save it in a database or other storage device.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to persist the last value selected by user, `UserSetting` is the best place to save such values.

Declare user setting values as -

Right click your project >> Navigate to Properties >> Settings

Say the value is EmployeeNameCombovalue, then you can read the value like this -

```
var empNameVal = Properties.Settings.Default.EmployeeNameCombovalue;
```

And to save some value in it -

```
Properties.Settings.Default["EmployeeNameCombovalue"] = cboEmpName.Text;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

So next time, when the program stars, you check if the value is there in user setting, if yes, set it to the combobox.

> But, if it is not just about saving a particular value, and you want to
>   save all the drop drop down values, then I suggest to store these
>   values in some persistent storage like DB, and bind your combobox from
>   that data. And whenever you add a new value to it, add the same in DB
>   as well and update your combobox data source.
>
> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8160f6f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: This is the kind of thing I do.

Answer (score 0):

There are various options available.

At some point, the answer boils down to a matter of urgency. I'd say you'll end up with these options:

1. You could store in the local file system, and read them again when form is loaded.
2. Serialize and store it in the registry (HKEY_CURRENT_USER - user specific)
3. Store it in the database and retrieve it again when needed.
4. [`.NET Application settings`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4s6c3a0.aspx), provides the easiest way to access your 
   settings at runtime (Check this [`Example`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(VS.80).aspx)).